# How do i call a FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs() method using my own custom class loader in java?

Tags: java, object, dynamic, casting, classloader

When I try to call a FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs() method using my own class loader it retuns the raw Object. But i have to store the retun values in Collection. How i will type cast it? In normal case  FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs() returns a iterator of  java.io.File.

FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs() is available in commons.io-2.4.jar

I am using a following code to call this method

```
        MyLoader c=new MyLoader();
        Class cls=c.loadClass("org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter");
        IOFileFilter directory=(IOFileFilter)cls.getField("DIRECTORY").get(null);
        cls=c.loadClass("org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils");
        File folder = new File(filePath);

        Collection<File> files=(Collection<File>)cls.getMethod("listFilesAndDirs", new Class[]{File.class,IOFileFilter.class,IOFileFilter.class}).invoke(null, new Object[]{new File(filePath), new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE), directory});
```

Kindly suggest me to access this method using custom class loader.

Comment: What's the problem with type casting ?

Comment: I am getting a "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Collection<File>" warning from eclipse.

Comment: no problem with that .. this is because at compile time eclipse does not know the type of class object this raw Object holding. It shall run without any issues